# Log4j2 in a webapp: MongoCleaner thread creates memory leaks

Tags: mongodb, web-applications, log4j2

I'm using log4j 2 with a MongoDBAppender in a webapp (servlet spec 2.5).

Here the web.xml:

```xml
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<filter>
    <filter-name>log4jServletFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>log4jServletFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ASYNC</dispatcher><!-- Servlet 3.0 w/ disabled auto-initialization 
        only; not supported in 2.5 -->
</filter-mapping>
```

Here the log4j2 configuration:

```xml
<Configuration status="warn">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="MongoDbServer">$${jndi:MongoDB.serverAddress.1.host}:$${jndi:MongoDB.serverAddress.1.port}</Property>
        <Property name="MongoDbPassword">$${jndi:MongoDB.password}</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <NoSql name="databaseAppender">
            <MongoDb databaseName="LOGS" collectionName="test"
                server="${MongoDbServer}" username="LOGS" password="${MongoDbPassword}" />
        </NoSql>
        <Async name="Async">
            <AppenderRef ref="databaseAppender" />
        </Async>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="Async" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

When i undeply the webapp, this error log appears:

```
SEVERE: A web application appears to have started a thread named [MongoCleaner665622824] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
```

Any suggestion?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have found a bug. Can you raise this in the log4j2 Jira issue tracker?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to close all instances of [`com.mongodb.MongoClient`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.10.0/com/mongodb/MongoClient.html). e.g:

```
MongoClient mongoClient= new MongoClient();

// Do something

mongoClient.close();
```